# A noun in English to substitute for "hysterical person"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a noun in English for a hysterical person? As far as I have gathered from dictionaries, "hysterical" is only an adjective. It is not a noun.

So, is there any noun that would fit in instead "hysterical person"

For example,

> "Why are you right away starting shouting? Can't you explain things to him
> in a calmer way? You are such a ______________ !"

Comment: "Drama queen" is the only term immediately coming to mind, though it's certainly very informal. I couldn't find any really good synonyms for that when I went hunting, either. Also - I know this isn't the point of your question, but I can't help myself - if this is for an actual conversation, then insulting somebody while asking them to speak calmly is not an advisable strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe "hysteric" is the word that you are looking for.It's a noun that describes a person suffering from hysteria

Comment: Surprisingly, the answer was even closer that I thought!

Answer (score 0):

***lunatic*** - emphasis on being irrational

***nut*** or ***nutcase***- a foolish, eccentric, or crazy person

***bully*** - emphasizes aggression

***loudmouth*** - given to loud, offensive talk

I prefer this: ***loudmouthed nutcase***.